# Application Qt and Qwt won't run from menu

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

Greetings for the first time:

Usually I can work my way through problems like this but I think I need help for this one.

I have developed a small utility for myself to plot some data using Qt and Qwt under Mint.  When I run the application from Qt Creator everything works fine.  Once I added (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.3/lib") to my .bashrc file, I can invoke the application from the terminal with “./PlotAccountsChange” and it woks.  Also the ldd command shows all dependencies have been found.

The problem I am having is that the application can not be invoked from the Nemo file manager, or from the menu system if I add the link to the executable in the menu, or from a link to the executable placed on the desktop.  In all of these cases I get no indication at all, just nothing happens.  Any other application that I have created using Qt but that doesn’t use Qwt invokes without problems.

Thank you, regards,
B Kace

Comment: I could not find any way to edit my original question so I had to describe how I got the solution this way.

I have found a way to fix the problem.  A Qwt expert from another forum advised me to use the QMAKE_RPATHDR directive in the .pro file and that would add the Qwt library path to the compiled application.

Regards,
B Kace